# How do I access $location from within an angular-chart.js onClick event handler?

Tags: angularjs

I want to switch to a new URL when a user clicks the bar in an angular-chart bar chart. I'm getting into the event handler, but the app never changes URLs.

The angular-chart directive looks like this:

```
<canvas id="prCosts" class="chart chart-bar"
        chart-data="prCosts.data"
        chart-labels="prCosts.labels" chart-options="prCosts.options"
        chart-series="prCosts.series"
        chart-dataset-override="prCosts.datasetOverride"
        chart-click="onClick"
</canvas>
```

The pertinent code in the controller looks like this:

```
$scope.prCosts.data = ...
$scope.prCosts.labels = ...
$scope.prCosts.options = ...
$scope.prCosts.series = ...
$scope.datasetOverride = ...
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt)
{
  var pr = points[0]._view.label;
  $location.url('/details?pr=' + pr);
};
```

The onClick function grabs a label from the chart and uses it as an argument in the URL. The function executes without errors, but the app doesn't switch to the new URL.

I've used this same code in another place in the app (but not in an event handler), and it works fine. This leads me to believe I have a scope issue. How do I get the correct scope for the $location.url() invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var that = this;

$scope.prCosts.data = ...
$scope.prCosts.labels = ...
$scope.prCosts.options = ...
$scope.prCosts.series = ...
$scope.datasetOverride = ...
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt)
{
  var pr = points[0]._view.label;
  that.$location.url('/details?pr=' + pr);
};
```

Comment: I get an error stating `that.$location` is undefined.

Comment: Is location injected?

Comment: Yes, it's injected into the controller. Not sure what's going on inside the directive

Comment: `angular.module('summaryCtrl', ['chart.js'])
  
  .controller('SummaryController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$location', '$interval', 'session',
                                    function ($scope, $http, $log, $location, $interval, session)
  {`

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's working now, though I'm not sure I understand exactly why. I added a `$scope.$apply()` after the `$location.url(...)` invocation.

```
$scope.prCosts.data = ...
$scope.prCosts.labels = ...
$scope.prCosts.options = ...
$scope.prCosts.series = ...
$scope.datasetOverride = ...
$scope.onClick = function (points, evt)
{
  var pr = points[0]._view.label;
  $location.url('/details?pr=' + pr);
  $scope.$apply();
};
```

Guess I will need to dig into `$apply()` to figure out what makes this necessary.